# Самопроизвольная смена цвета background

Tags: java, android, android-style

Есть приложение под Android. Построено на `Activity` + `Fragment`'ы. В приложении (в стилях `style.xml`) реализованы две темы: светлая и темная. В `onCreate` `Activity` до метода `setContentView()`, а также в `onResume()` прописан простой код:

```
// style - int переменная, которой присваивается 0/1 из SharedPreferences
switch (style) {
    case 0:
        setTheme(R.style.AppThemeLight);
        break;
    case 1:
        setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Проблема состоит в следующем. Когда пользователь сворачивает приложение на продолжительное время, то после разворота цвет фона (`background`) меняется на противоположный (из другого стиля). Цвета `Toolbar`, `NavigationDrawer`, `primaryTextColor`, `secondaryTextColor` и другие остаются на месте.

В чем может быть проблема ?

P.S.: первым решением было вынести блок кода по смене стиля из `Activity` в класс `MyAppClass`, который расширен `Activity` и прописан в манифесте. Но толка от этого не было.

**UPD0**

`style.xml -> LightTheme`

```
 <style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/aa_primaryColor_lightTheme</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/aa_primaryDarkColor_lightTheme</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/aa_accentColor_lightTheme</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/aa_backgroundColor_lightTheme</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/aa_foregroundColor_lightTheme</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/aa_primaryTextColor_lightTheme</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/aa_secondaryTextColor_lightTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/aa_windowBackgroundColor_lightTheme</item>
</style>
```

// изменяется на противоположный цвет `android:windowBackground`

**UPD1**

Но, если установить Light стиль, то после длительного времяпровождения в свернутом виде, приложение не меняет свой `android:windowBackground` на противоположный. Проблема только в темной схеме.

**UPD2**

Если поменять местами в `switch-case` `Light` и `Dark` темы, то все равное после долгого простоя экран окрашивается в белый цвет, а все остальное как положено.

Comment: Укажите прямо стилям background, иначе они будут по default брать заданный цвет в зависимости от стиля, что остается под "занавесом". 
Или помимо стиля меняйте прямо нужный background в switch

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, есть у меня в стилях `<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/aa_windowBackgroundColor_lightTheme</item>` для светлой и для темной аналогичная строка.
А никаких дефолтных значений нет. Есть два стиля и все.

Comment: покажите в коде ваши стили, станет понятней.

Comment: windowBackground или background ) ?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, обновил вопрос.

Comment: А вы стиль назначаете до или после `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`? Надо до и в `onResume()` это делать не надо ибо не подействует, вроде.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, пока все хорошо. Странно, что я раньше разместил вызов темы после супер конструктора. Если желаете, то оформляйте ответ, я зачту его как верный. Если не захотите, то сам оформлю для будущих читателей ruSO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стиль назначать надо до вызова `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` в методе `onCreate` класса активити.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, Юрий! Я совершенно забыл об этом. :-)